# how to redirect the page in angularjs spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, redirect, location

Angular js is the single page application and spring have ModelAndView method is not working for angular js. how to move the next page in angular js spring MVC

This is my angular js code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
 app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', '$location',function($scope,$resource,$http,$location) 
    {
    $scope.creates = function()
             {
                    User = $resource(
                            "dostudentregister",
                            {},
                             {method:'POST',isArray:false}
                    );

                    var userBean = {};

                    userBean.name = $scope.myforms.name;
                    userBean.email = $scope.myforms.email;
                    userBean.eventid = $scope.myforms.eventid;
                    userBean.rollno = $scope.myforms.rollno;
                    userBean.password = $scope.myforms.password;

                    $scope.Message = User.save(userBean);

                    $scope.myforms.name="";
                    $scope.myforms.email="";
                    $scope.myforms.eventid="";
                    $scope.myforms.rollno="";
                    $scope.myforms.password="";

                    $location.path('/opentoall.jsp');
                };
}]);
```

spring controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dostudentregister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object studentregisteration(@RequestBody UserBeans userBean, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
        {
            if(eventregister.studentregisteration(userBean) !=null)
            {
                System.out.println("inserted");
            }

        }
        return "opentoall";
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have routing on both client and server.

Comment: Sir, How to use routing I use ng-route but the whole angular not working

Comment: You can use Spring to serve APIs while angular does the routing. Do not route in Spring.